# What is the most useful multi-purpose open-source library for java?

Tags: java, open-source

Are there any open-source libraries that all programmers should know about? I'm thinking
something general, a sort of extension to the standard `java.util` that contains basic functions that are useful for all kinds of application.

Comment: This question probably should be edited to request 1 library per answer so that voting works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Apache Commons
- Log4j
- Google collections

Answer (score 6):

The [Spring framework](http://www.springframework.org/) is surprisingly general purpose. I started by just using it as a configuration management tool, but then realized how helpful dependency injection is when doing test-driven development. Then I slowly discovered many useful modules hidden in the corners of Spring.

Answer (score 4):

Apache's [Jakarta Commons](http://commons.apache.org/).

Answer (score 3):

The [Google Collections API](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) is pretty handy if you use lots of, well, Collections...

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth saying that the first thing to do is get to know the libraries in the newer versions of Java. A lot of ideas have worked their way back into java - java.util.concurrent, java.nio, and javax.xml

Answer (score 3):

[Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org) offers first-class function values, immutable lists/arrays, lazy/infinite streams, tuple types, either types, optional values (type-safe alternative to null). Works well in conjunction with Google Collections or the java.util collections.

It also provides handy concurrency abstractions like parallel strategies, parallel list/array functors, actor concurrency, and composable light-weight processes.

Answer (score 2):

lambdaj is a thread safe library of static methods that provides an internal DSL to manipulate collections in a pseudo-functional and statically typed way without explicitly iterating on them. It eliminates the burden to write (often poorly readable) loops while iterating over collections.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good start. http://java-sources.org/

Answer (score 2):

Google Collections migrated to great [Guava Libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) . It contains some common utilities, string matcher, splitter, joiner, IO utils etc.

Answer (score 0):

[JXL](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) for Excel workbook creation/edition. I work in a bank and the multipurpose report tool for diary work is Excel. Whatever appliction we do must import/export from/to Excel. The only fail it's that it has memory problems with large workbooks and formating it's a little obscure

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[jmate](http://code.google.com/p/jmate/)** project. It contains really helpful methods for strings, collections and IO operations (for now).

Look some [examples here](http://javaadami.blogspot.com/2008/08/whenever-scripting-language-wants-to.html).

Answer (score 0):

Lately I was trying to find answer to this question. I made some data analysis for this, you can find results [here](http://www.77dev.com/2014/05/java-trends-top-100-mostly-used.html) and [here](http://www.77dev.com/2014/05/what-are-most-popular-java-libraries.html).