# (Java) Good Libraries and What they are

Tags: java, resources, duplicates

Lets compile a list of 3rd party java libraries that we like and/or find useful.

I will post my choices as a reply

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213/what-is-the-most-useful-multi-purpose-open-source-library-for-java

Comment: Seems very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-java-libraries

Comment: This was already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-java-libraries

Comment: Ah I didnt see that thread, however those all all free libraries... but to be honest I don't think I personally would be able to contribute a library that isnt free.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911753/what-are-the-most-useful-java-libs-that-help-you-avoid-writing-repetitive-code isn't specific to free libraries.

Comment: Not a question, but since it's CW I'm kinda meh about the whole closing thing.

Comment: Close - dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130095/most-useful-free-java-libraries

Comment: If this is gonna remain open, perhaps edit it to cover only non-free libs? (Because free libs really are quite throughly listed in 130095.) @Matthew: pointing to a closed question with zero answers doesn't help much.

Answer (score 3):

### [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)

Google Collections rules. Gives you predicates, BiMaps, synchronization wrappers around java.util collections, etc.

Answer (score 2):

### [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/)

"Apache Lucene is a high-performance, full-featured text search engine library written entirely in Java. It is a technology suitable for nearly any application that requires full-text search, especially cross-platform."

Lucene never fails to astonish me, with its performance, clean implementation, and overall elegance.  It's a wonderful piece of work.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache log4j™ 1.2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)

Log4j is a flexible logging library, an open source project from Apache

Answer (score 1):

### [SwingX](http://swinglabs.org/)

> SwingX is all about Swing components.
>   It focuses both on extensions to
>   existing Swing components as well as
>   brand new ones. SwingX contains a lot
>   of great components that you can use
>   in your applications today.

Answer (score 1):

### [SQLiteJDBC](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/)

Java JDBC driver for SQLite. It runs using either a native code library 100% Pure Java driver based on NestedVM emulation.

Answer (score 0):

### [Eclipse Link](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)

> The Eclipse Persistence Services
>   Project (EclipseLink) delivers a
>   comprehensive open-source Java
>   persistence solution. EclipseLink
>   focuses on standards with advanced
>   features, performance and scalability
>   for enterprise software developers
>   across data sources, formats, and
>   containers.

Answer (score 0):

### [Golden T Game Engine (GTGE)](http://www.goldenstudios.or.id/products/GTGE/)

> Golden T Game Engine (GTGE) is an
>   advanced cross-platform game
>   programming library written in Java
>   language. GTGE library provides a
>   complete routines for making 2D game
>   from low level routines such as
>   hardware accelerated 2D graphics,
>   mouse and keyboard input, audio
>   support, game timing, to game specific
>   routines such as sprite, background,
>   collision detection.

Answer (score 0):

### [FEST (Fixtures for Easy Software Testing)](http://fest.easytesting.org)

Excellent and easy-to-use library for unit testing Swing and JavaFX UI. Also has interesting mock and assertion modules.