# What are the top 3 productivity improving libraries for core java?

Tags: java

Compared with other languages, Java sometimes is pretty "chatty" and some of the core libraries are considered cumbersome by a lot of programmers. Over the last years an tremendous zoo of small libraries has evolved, which try to "fix" a single aspect of these e.g. Joda Time, guava-libraries, lambdaj

What are the top three libraries that can improve productivity when working with core Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Java) Good Libraries and What they are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046597/java-good-libraries-and-what-they-are)

Comment: That depends entirely on what you are trying to do. Can you say what you are doing? A good starting list is http://java-source.net/ BTW: I don't use any of the libraries you suggest. ;) The problem I have with functional libraires is that they can be even more chatty in Java due to its syntax (Java 8's closures will improve this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can definitely mention

1. [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)
2. [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) - dependency injector
3. [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/) - unless all your users live in the same place
4. [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) - mocking framework